# Problems creating an S3 bucket with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created a very simple terraform file.

#main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"  # Set your desired region
}
    
locals {
   bucket_name = "noname-production-default-storage"
}
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "noname-production-s3" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
}
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "noname-s3-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.noname-production-s3.id
    
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
       {
          Sid = "PublicReadGetObject",
          Effect = "Allow",
          Principal = "*",
          Action = "s3:GetObject",
          Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}/*"
       }
     ]
  })
}
```

But I get an:

> Error: putting S3 policy: AccessDenied: Access Denied

I have a very general Policy for my IAM user:

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:*",
                    "s3-object-lambda:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

What permission do I miss? Or is there a problem with my terraform example?

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419099/access-denied-when-creating-s3-bucket-acl-s3-policy-using-terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your S3 bucket is [blocking all public access](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-s3-automatically-enable-block-public-access-disable-access-control-lists-buckets-april-2023/), which means it is created with all four of the bucket-level settings enabled:

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access
  control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access
  control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public
  bucket or access point policies
- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through
  any public bucket or access point policies

You can read more about those settings [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/).

Because of the third one, all attempts to set a bucket policy policy that grants public access (which is your case) will be rejected with a 403 Access Denied error.
You can control those settings and disable the block public access check by using a separate Terraform resource called `aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block`, like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.noname-production-s3.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

This will allow you to attach the resource policy to the S3 bucket. You may want to add `depends_on: [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.example]` to your `aws_s3_bucket_policy` so that the public access is enabled before attaching the policy.

Comment: Thank you. I had to set restrict_public_buckets = false to make my bucket public. Is there any reason for not doing this? I am serving just static web files for my website